# How to make a mask for picking some special indices in tensorflow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, mask

Here is a example code. I would like to use tf.scatter_nd to assign values to a new tensor. Like, updated_values = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(indices_tf, -1), values_tf, tf.shape(values_tf)). There are some repetitive indices in indices tensor which causes the adding trouble in updated_values tensor. I would like to assign only one accroding to info tensor that always has the same shape with indices tensor. The code describes the details.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

info =    np.array([0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1])

indices = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2])
values = np.array([7, 6, 4, 9, 2, 1, 10])

delta_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(info, tf.int32)
indices_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(indices, tf.int32)
values_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(values, tf.float32)

updated_values = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(indices_tf, -1), values_tf, tf.shape(values_tf))

sess = tf.Session()

updated_values_ = sess.run(updated_values)
print(updated_values_)

# The updated_values_ is [7. 18. 14.  0.  0.  0.  0.].
# I would like tf.scatter_nd to assign only one value to updated_values 
# at repetitive indices not adding them.
# 
# So I want to make a mask from indices according to info, 
# the rule is that when meeting repetitive index in indices, 
# the mask will compare the values in info, then reset the maximum value to 1, the others to 0.
#    info: [0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1]
# indices: [0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
#    mask: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
# 
# In this example, the mask will reset the position at 0, 3, 6 in info to 1, the others to 0.
# So the mask is [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0].

mask = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]) # the desired mask
mask_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, tf.float32)
updated_valuess = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(indices_tf, -1), values_tf * mask_tf, tf.shape(values_tf))

updated_valuess_ = sess.run(updated_valuess)
print(updated_valuess_) # This output [7. 2. 4. 0. 0. 0. 0.] is what I want.
```

How to generate this mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Approach 1

This should work,

```
vals = tf.constant([0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1], dtype=tf.int64)
ind = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2], dtype=tf.int64)

un, _  = tf.unique(ind)
res = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.one_hot(tf.argmax(vals * tf.cast(tf.equal(ind, x), tf.int64)), depth=ind.shape[0], dtype=tf.int64), un), 
    axis=0)
```

**Edit**

### Approach 2

`map_fn` is a slow operation. So, if you use that option, you should also expect slowness. Unless you set `parallel_iteration` argument and execute it in `non-eager` mode, it will run sequentially. Therefore, the following solution will be faster.

Here, I'm using `RaggedTensor` and finding maximum of each element belonging to a given segment. However, to use RaggedTensors, you have to have the segment IDs sorted therefore, sorting and un-sorting is involved.

```
vals = tf.constant([0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1], dtype=tf.int64)
ind = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2], dtype=tf.int64)

sort_args = tf.argsort(ind)
sort_vals = tf.gather(vals, sort_args)
sort_inds = tf.gather(ind, sort_args)

ragged = tf.RaggedTensor.from_value_rowids(
    values=sort_vals,
    value_rowids=sort_inds)
max_vals = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_max(ragged, axis=1),[-1,1])

res = tf.cast(tf.equal(ragged, max_vals).values, tf.int32)
res_unsort = tf.gather(res, sort_args)
```

### Results (On Colab GPU)

- Approach 1 (No parallel execution): 10 loops, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop
- Approach 2: 10 loops, best of 3: 490 µs per loop

You can see that approach 2 is way faster.

Comment: Glad it worked. If you're happy with the answer please accept it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Ok, I accept it. But I have a puzzle, why tf.map_fn eats up my computer memory when ind tensor gets longer? Shouldn't it use the GPU memory? What's more, it also uses all my cpu power.

Comment: @HuachunWang So practically how long are your vectors (on average)? I'll have a think about a more efficient solution for this.

Comment: @HuachunWang edited my answer with a more efficient solution

Comment: my tensorflow is 1.8.0, I will update it to 2.0, and try your approach 2. I think your solution is good enough for me. Thanks again!